# wlst script to update the application

Tags: shell, wlst

I have to write a shell script in which I need to use some wlst commands to update the two application(ear and war file). The problem is when I'm updating 
The command only one application(say ear file) gets updated. how can I update the both application. please refer the below code.

```
echo"start updating the weblogic services"
cd /$LOGNAME/products/middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/bin
./wlst.sh 
connect('sample','sample123','t3://host:port')
edit()
startEdit()
updateApplication('SPLService.ear','/dev/ouaf/splebase/mdmdev8/splapp/applications')
updateApplication('SPLWeb.ear','/dev/ouaf/splebase/mdmdev8/splapp/applications')
save()
activate()
disconnect()
exit()
```

hints: "dev" is the environment name on which I'm trying to run the script.

Comment: I've never worked with wlst, but I've worked with the weblogic console. And if can rember right, in the console you have to go through the whole workflow for each single application.

Comment: ok. but in console one can update the application in a single step..right? I mean we don't need to edit and activate for each one.in a single step we can activate after updating of both applications.

Comment: As I wrote: "if I can remember right..."